# alternative to gdi when writing text editor in winapi

Tags: windows, winapi, text, editor, gdi

Is there some alternative to GDI when one want to 
write nice working, fast text editor under
winapi? I want something what would work
with older windows versions for example XP, too.
I heard that GDI is slow, maybe there is something 
more proper to GDI when writng text editor?
Does maybe somebody know what to that purpose 
are using miscleanous nice text editors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDI is not too fast. But probably for editor, it should be sufficient. It also depends on the inteligence of the paint algorithm. When being edited, for example, you should only re-render the affected line(s). Even when inserting new lines, you may just scroll most of the ones below with `ScrollWindow()` or `ScrollWindowEx()`.

As an alternative you may look at Uniscribe (USP10.DLL). However I am not sure whether it
relies on GDI or not. It is more or less replacement of `TextOut()` and similar GDI functions to support properly different scripting systems, including aspects like right-to-left reading, mixtures of left-to-right and right-to-left (e.g. arabian with embedded European personal names etc.)

Then there is also DirectWrite, which is supposed to be used together with Direct2D. That should be faster as Direct2D offloads a lot work to graphics card, while GDI eats mainly CPU and system memory. Note however these APIs are only available since Windows 7.

Comment: tnx for very nice info - I will try to read about uniscribe i never heard of, Doesnt you know maybe what approach are using present nice editors - I wonder if it is GDI mostly or something different

Comment: also think that maybe gdi would be enough, but if there is something more fast/clear/low-lewel I would like to test it, becuse gdi drawing routines doesnt seem quite ok for me

Comment: There is nothing lower level then GDI. AFAIK, GDI is not based on something more lower level what can be easily used. As said, a faster alternative is the Direct2D+DirectWrite. But that is quite new. Perhaps DirectWrite with fallbacking into GDI or Uniscribe on older windows version is the right way, although twice that many work to go.

Comment: alrite it seem quite clear, So it would be : if one have to draw true type fonts in windows xp GDI is one and only option (or he has to write its own true type font rasterizer over some DX or pixel blitter)... probably it can be true but was not to much clear to me